# Understanding preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I would like to check if string consists only of small letters or underscores.
Does the following returns true if string meets this condition? Is any better way to do this?

```
preg_match('/[^a-z_]/', $category_address)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code tests if it contains anything *other* than letter or underscore. So if this test succeeds, then it means the string is not valid.

Comment: This test returns 1 when the condition is false, it searches the first character that is not a lowercase ascii letter or an underscore. This test is efficient (more than describing all the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `+` quantifier with anchors:

```
preg_match('/\A[a-z_]+\z/', $category_address)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\A`  - start of string
- `[a-z_]+` - 1 or more (due to the greedy quantifier `+`) characters defined in the character class: either lowercase ASCII letters or `_`
- `\z` - the very  end of string

If an empty string should be matched, too, replace the `+` quantifier with a `*` one that matches *zero or more occurrences* of the quantified subpattern.

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for pointing out this + qualifier!